# Why is malloc() allocating more memory than demanded and how can I disable malloc from doing this in Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, c, macos, memory-management, malloc

I am making a program for a robot which stores a Maze as a Multi-Dimensional Dynamic Adjacency Array, and since the nodes will be discovered along the Maze Traversal, I am trying to allocate initial memory for it and then reallocate memory once a new node is found. However, I once realized that I was storing more data than I had allocated using `malloc` (I had forgotten to use `realloc`) and despite that it was not giving me some sort of a segmentation fault or some other error. So I was interested to know:

1. Why does malloc allocate more memory than required?
2. How can I disable this so that I can properly debug my program? I am sure that the robot would not have loads of heap memory like my 16GB RAM MacBook so I would want to know if my program works within the memory I had allocated to it in the program.

Thank you for your response!

Comment: 'Why does malloc allocate more memory than required?' that is an erroneous conclusion.

Comment: ...because "it was not giving me some sort of a segmentation fault" doesn't mean you're good.

Comment: I know, that is precisely why I am asking that how can I properly make the program allocate as much memory as I did so that it actually gives me the error when I allocate more memory.

Comment: @DanishAmjadAlvi you cannot.  Segfaults/AV are raised by the OS for illegal memory accesses,  Unfortunately for you, C malloc() is a sub-allocator.  Overrunning the bounds of malloc() does not necessarily generate an illegal memory access hardware excpetion to the OS.

Comment: As Murphy's Law says, 'If something might go wrong, it will go wrong at the worst possible time'. Keep in mind my program will be compiled later on a robot which will have few MBs of RAM so I do not want any errors on it. Plus whats the point of programming if we had to depend on uncertainty? We should use no more memory than allocated as the extra memory we are getting might not be available.

Comment: Put another way.  You malloc one byte.  malloc has no space so it asks OS for the minimum available.  The OS gives it one page, ie. 8K.   You write 1K into your one-byte malloced buffer.  OS does not care because it's still inside the page.  OK, your program is stuffed, but the OS will not stop it at that stage.

Comment: The OS usually cannot give you the exact bytes you wanted, it gives you pages of 4k or so. malloc then organizes the page into chunks and writing past the end of a chunk may stay on the page you allocated, so as far as the OS is concerned you didn't access anything you didn't allocate. I recommend using [AddressSanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) which will catch these kinds of errors. Valgrind is an alternative.

Comment: @DanishAmjadAlvi You did not understand the key point. Accessing out of allocated range does not necessarily produces an error message, but it is an error and it leads to undefined behavior. You accessed memory that is *not allocated* and should not be accessed. Your conclusion was wrong: malloc not necessarily allocated more than you asked. It's you, who crossed the line. There is no any uncertainty.

Comment: I see so there is no way to 'fix' allocated memory? Is there any way that the program does not allow me to access more memory than I had allocated for myself?

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *7.22.3 Memory management functions 1 [...] The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement[...]* You cannot expect exact-sized allocations.

Comment: @DanishAmjadAlvi: What that needs to be fixed is your code; it should not attempt to acces memory outside the bounds of what you have allocated for yourself.  You have to accurately keep track of what you have allocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike what most people think, malloc does not allocate the memory directly from the kernel. Instead, it takes a chunk of memory from the kernel, and then manages that chunk in user space with a data structure. That data structure used to be a heap, hence calling it "heap memory".

The practical upshot of the above is that the memory allocated using malloc does not have invalid memory around it. Overstepping the memory by a little will not, in fact, cause your program to crash.

In addition to the above, malloc itself does not allocate in any size you wish. It usually allocates chunks in multiples of 8, 16 or 32 bytes, depending on the data structure used to manage the heap. When you allocate 1 byte with malloc, you are actually getting around 15 bytes that will never be used by anyone. Overwriting those bytes will not cause any noticeable ill effect.

If you want to make sure your program works with a small amount of memory, rlimit/ulimit and co are your friends. If you want to make sure you are not overstepping your allocated buffers, I strongly recommend the address sanitizer. Compile (both clang and gcc) with `-fsanitize=address`, and your program will crash as soon as you overstep your buffers. This comes at a performance cost, of course.

I'll also add that hardware access control are only possible on page boundaries. On Intel, that's 4096 bytes. Even for memory allocated from the kernel, accesses past the end of the allocation will not trigger a segmentation fault if they do not step outside the allocated page.

Comment: Thank you! However, is it possible you kindly give me an example of a code where you are trying to access memory out of your buffer and it gives you an error (and conversely) you are trying to access memory within your buffer and it does not give an error?

Comment: No need to give an example, it worked with my own code! I tried allocating some extra values out of the buffer and it gave me the buffer map. Thank you for your cooperation sir!

Answer (score 1):

1. It doesn't, you just got lucky.  Your program invoked undefined behavior, so anything could have happened.
2. If you want to run your program in a constrained environment, to simulate the fact that your target machine has limited memory, you can.  Before launching your program, in your shell, run this command: `ulimit -Sv 1000`.  It's in kilobytes, so 1000 means 1 megabyte.

For more on ulimit, see here: http://ss64.com/osx/ulimit.html - you can use it on Linux too.

You can also use the C function [`setrlimit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) to do similar within your program, if you don't feel like running `ulimit` every time.